# Cannot get my child component to re render on props change

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am very new to React but trying my best to build something meaningful. But I am stuck with this problem for a few days. Here is my question :

I have this App Component :

```
function App() {
return (

    <Fragment>
        <HeadMenu />
        <TitleBanner componentTitle={this.props.location.pathname} />
        <Home />
    </Fragment>
);}
export default withRouter(App);
```

And this is the TitleBanner Component

```
class TitleBanner extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.componentTitle= props.componentTitle
    };
}

render() {

    return (
        <Grid container alignContent={'center'} >
            <Grid item xs={11}>
                <h2>
                    {this.componentTitle}
                </h2>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    );
};} 
 export default TitleBanner;
```

I wish my TitleBanner component's componentTitle props to update depending on the current location BUT whenever I change the location, the title does not update unless I manually refresh the page. 
I have succeeded updating it using Redux (I might have done it wrong though) but it looks like it refreshes the whole page while I only want to change a single title.

1. What are the simple solutions to update the TitleBanner title without rendering the other modules ?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: where are you using router?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things wrong in your code

**First:** In your App component you are using `this.props.location.pathname` but since its a functional component you should use the props from argument like

```
function App(props) {

    return (

        <Fragment>
            <HeadMenu />
            <TitleBanner componentTitle={props.location.pathname} />
            <Home />
        </Fragment>
    );

}
export default withRouter(App);
```

**Second:** In your `TitleBanner` component you are assigning the prop `componentTitle` to a class variable in constructor which won't be reassigned when the props change. Since you are directly using prop without any modification its recommended to use it directly from props itself

```
class TitleBanner extends React.Component {

    render() {

        return (
            <Grid container alignContent={'center'} >
                <Grid item xs={11}>
                    <h2>
                        {props.componentTitle}
                    </h2>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        );
    };

} 
export default TitleBanner;
```